# Why doesn't adding a message to Open Graph like button work?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, facebook-social-plugins

I'm developing a web app that uses custom Open Graph objects and actions,
in a web page showing an Open Graph object I have a Facebook like button (according to Facebook's developers documentation).

When a user is clicking on 'like' it first asks to confirm the like, 
after the like is confirmed, it opens a popup to add a comment to the like action.

The problem is that clicking on 'Post to Facebook' after adding a comment doesn't work, the comment is becoming gray for a second like its posting to Facebook, but then reverts back and the dialog stays open. no comment is posted to Facebook (the like does get posted).

Why is this happening? is it something I can fix ?

Why does the 'confirm' thing appear for the like action ? I read somewhere that it'll automatically disappear once people are using the app and confirming likies. is it true ?

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue. Have you found a fix?